# add js code on add to cart magento 1.9

Tags: javascript, magento

I tried to add this JS code on Magento 1.9 , but nothing happens when i click on add to cart button.

I added code in XML file ( i see that is ok when i see source code in page via browser ) :

and added this JS in folder JS/Carrello/cart.js :

```
$('.btn-cart').on('click', function () {
        var cart = $('.skip-cart');
        var imgtodrag = $(this).parent('.item').find("img").eq(0);
        if (imgtodrag) {
            var imgclone = imgtodrag.clone()
                .offset({
                top: imgtodrag.offset().top,
                left: imgtodrag.offset().left
            })
                .css({
                'opacity': '0.5',
                    'position': 'absolute',
                    'height': '150px',
                    'width': '150px',
                    'z-index': '100'
            })
                .appendTo($('body'))
                .animate({
                'top': cart.offset().top + 10,
                    'left': cart.offset().left + 10,
                    'width': 75,
                    'height': 75
            }, 1000, 'easeInOutExpo');

            setTimeout(function () {
                cart.effect("shake", {
                    times: 2
                }, 200);
            }, 1500);

            imgclone.animate({
                'width': 0,
                    'height': 0
            }, function () {
                $(this).detach()
            });
        }
    });
```

I followed this guide :
http://codepen.io/ElmahdiMahmoud/pen/tEeDn

Answer (score 0):

First of check any conflicts with prototype.

if that's the case replace $ with jQuery

Also, could you please explain how did you add your code using xml?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Sorry how i can check conflicts? i need to replace $ with jQuery ( words in code ) ? for adding xml i use incoo Xternal , and i have added code :<action method="addJs"><script>carrello/cart.js</script></action>     I'm sorry but I don't know well js and jquery :)

Comment: You can check the conflict using browser developers toolbar and yes you can replace $ with jQuery word.